# Why does running "os.system('cmd')" do nothing in Python?

Tags: python, command-prompt, os.system

I am trying to run Command Prompt commands using Python, but running my command seems to do nothing. The full command I pass to os.system is:

`'cmd /c "apt.bat"'`

This should run apt.bat, opening another program in the process. However, nothing happens. When I pass that same command to the Command Prompt manually, it runs correctly. So to try to hone in on the problem, I have tried running:

`os.system('cmd')`

but nothing happens. As far as I know, this should open the Command Prompt, but I could be wrong about that. To ensure that I have the correct syntax and that os.system isn't broken or something, I have also tried running:

`os.system('notepad')`

which opens notepad without issue. Is there something different about 'cmd' that would cause it to simply not open? Is there some syntax I am missing? Maybe permissions?

For reference, I am on Windows 10. Python 3.7, using Spyder 4.

Comment: `cmd` is not a command

Comment: Try: `os.system("start /wait cmd")`

Comment: I have updated my post to further clarify what I am trying to do. I am not simply trying to open the Command Prompt, but run a command from it. Does that help?

Comment: @JohnWendeborn I have updated my answer, let me know if that works :D

Answer (score -1):

Syntax: os.system(command)

command: It is of string type that tells which command to execute.

Return Value: On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process and on Windows, the return value is the value returned by the system shell after running command.

Thus when you run the following command from the python shell

```
os.system("cmd")
```

you get this output:

[image]

Which is similar to the output you get when you run the same command from the command line as well:

[image]

**I.e. The return value is the value returned by the system shell after running command.**

Thus to "run the command prompt using python", do this:

```
os.system("start cmd")
```

## Update

To run the specific command that you are trying you simply need to remove the single quotation marks, try this:

```
os.system("cmd /c apt.bat")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. Running ```apt /c apt.bat``` directly from command prompt works, but running ```os.system("cmd /c apt.bat")``` form Python does nothing.

Comment: @JohnWendeborn Interesting.... I am at a loss then, because I ran the exact same command on my end with the same path.. and it works.

Comment: `os.system("cmd")` and `os.system("cmd /c apt.bat")` didn't work for me at all

Comment: @MathCoder101 Unfortunately I am not sure why it is not working for you or OP. Take a look at this on my system https://imgur.com/gallery/RHiBkqk

Comment: Hmm. I moved the location of my Python script to the directory where 'apt.bat' is located, and now it seems to be working. 'apt.bat' is in my path, so I'm not sure why this would be the issue... So I have solved my own personal issues, but I will leave the question open for further answers/insight. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnWendeborn Thanks for the update, Upon seeing your comment I moved my ".bat " file to a different directory from my script (initially they were in the same directory). Now it is not working anymore. So maybe that was the root problem... hmm..

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that `cmd` is not a command. You should be using `os.system('start cmd')` or `subprocess.run('start', shell = True)` using the `subprocess` module.

Comment: if you try running "cmd" in a command prompt: you get ```'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```